# Jenkins Git reference repository path for tag

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm getting the following error message, if I use e.g. "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now" in Jenkins.:

```
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 1:

 ! [rejected]            v1.6.3-beta1 -> v1.6.3-beta1  (would clobber existing tag)
```

If I delete the tag `v1.6.3-beta1` on the remote Git server, "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now" in Jenkins runs without an error and building pipelines work.

If I repush a new created tag `v1.6.3-beta1` that was already deleted on the Git remote, "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now" in Jenkins is broken again. It seems Jenkins still has the local tag `v1.6.3-beta1` somewhere.

The problem I can not figure out where Jenkins stores the "local" tags / the reference Git repository.

Can anyone help me to find the location where Jenkins runs "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now" check, so I can delete the local tag by myself?

Answer (score 0):

Outside Jenkins, a simple forced fetch with [`git fetch -f`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt--f) would be enough

```
git fetch --tags -f
```

That should override any local tag.

With Jenkins, this issue pops up with Git 2.20+: [issue JENKINS-55284](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55284).

The git client plugin 2.7.6 released January 10, 2019, should include a force option.

Comment: thx for your answer. What do you mean by "Outside Jenkins"? I tried `git fetch --tags -f` in a branch on Jenkins with the new tag pushed, but the problem is still there. What could be the problem?

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE I meant in command-line, outside a Jenkins job execution. The error you see is done at the beginning of the job, when Jenkins update its workspace with the latest from the Git repository, so *before* any shell step command you might try in that same Jenkins job.

Comment: I tried it in the command line on the Jenkins server in a branch workspace. In which folder I have to execute that command for the Jenkins function "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now"?

Comment: Not sure, there should be a workspace folder associated with that job.